# Display Free Shipping badge underneath the ITEM TITLE and underneath the PRICE on a single product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to Display Free Shipping badge underneath the ITEM TITLE (example attached) and underneath the PRICE on a single product pag.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usYni.png)

I found the below code but not sure what changes to make in order to achieve the above.

PS: it is only for items with no shipping class.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'single_product_label', 10 );
function single_product_label() {

    global $product;
    if ( empty( $product->get_shipping_class() ) ) {
        echo '<span class="freedel">Free UK Delivery</span>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To achive the result as in the example picture you have to change the hook you're using.

The hook `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title` will execute before the product title just as it states.

Instead you should use `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` which executes after the product information but before the add to cart button.

Businessbloomer.com have a wonderful visual guide to the hooks on the Woocommerce archive page that I recommend you take a look at: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/

This is what your code should look like instead:
Obviously you will have to style it with css to get the same result as in the picture though.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'archive_product_label', 10 );
function archive_product_label() {
    global $product;
    if ( empty( $product->get_shipping_class() ) ) {
        echo '<span class="freedel">Free UK Delivery</span>';
    }
}
```

The example picture and code you used, all look like you want this on the archive page and not on the single product page as you have written. But for good measure I'll add the link for the visual guide to the single product page and add the code for that aswell.

Single product page visual hook guide: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

Here are a few hooks you could use but I'm guessing the one you want is the `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form`

Here's the code for the single product page:
Notice that I changed the above function name to archive_product_label and I'm now calling this single_product_label instead. This is to avoid conflict and to make it easier to locate if you need to change the code sometime in the future.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'single_product_label', 10 );
function single_product_label() {
    global $product;
    if ( empty( $product->get_shipping_class() ) ) {
        echo '<span class="freedel">Free UK Delivery</span>';
    }
}
```

If you always want the same text on both archive and single product page you could also bind the two different actions to the same function

Like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'free_shipping_product_label', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'free_shipping_product_label', 10 );
function free_shipping_product_label() {
    global $product;
    if ( empty( $product->get_shipping_class() ) ) {
        echo '<span class="freedel">Free UK Delivery</span>';
    }
}
```

Hope this answers your question and teaches you a little bit about how hooks, functions and actions work in wordpress/woocommerce.

Have a great day! :)